# why i am not able to view with classbased (list view )but for function based view it is working fine?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

My question: why i am not able to view search only ayan rand's book with classbased list view?

this is my function based view for store list, and i am retrieving all my book objects and rendering in HTML and it is working fine.

But using classbasedview "SearchBookDetail" i am not able to get the specified book details as denoted .

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import  HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView

def store_listView(request,):
      queryset=Book.objects.all()

      context={
           "objects_list":queryset
      }
      return render(request,'bookstores/store.html',context)

class SearchBookDetail(ListView):
    template_name = "bookstores/store.html"
    queryset = Book.objects.filter(author__icontains='Ayan Rand')
    print("Ayan Rand query set", queryset)
```

Urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.views.generic import TemplateView
 from store.views import (Home,ContactView,LoginView,
                     store_listView,
                     SearchBookDetail,
                     book_createview,
                     QuoteslistView,
                    AyanRandBookDetail,
                     quotesFunctionView)

 urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$',Home.as_view()),
   url(r'^contact/$',ContactView.as_view()),
   url(r'^login/$',LoginView.as_view()),
   url(r'^store/$',store_listView),
   url(r'^store/AyanRandBookDetail/$',AyanRandBookDetail.as_view()),
   url(r'^store/SearchBookDetail/$',SearchBookDetail.as_view()),
   url(r'^quotes/$',quotesFunctionView)]
```

store.html:

```
 {% extends "home.html" %}
 {% block head_title %}Store || {{ block.super }} {% endblock head_title %}
 {% block content %}
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Store</title>
 </head>

 <h6>Books available</h6>
 <ul>
   {% for obj in objects_list %}
   <li>{{obj}}<br>
    {{obj.book_image}} <br>
    {{obj.description}} <br>
    {{obj.author}}<br>
    {{obj.genre}}<br>
    {{obj.price}}<br>
    </li>

   {% endfor %}
</ul>


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You haven't given us any idea what is wrong. What happens, and how is that different from what you expect?

Comment: i am able to view all bookobjects with this -"http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/"  but while i am using "http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/SearchBookDetail/ " i am not able to view anything. while i am not able to see data

Comment: And what does the template contain?

Comment: store.html:{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block head_title %}Store || {{ block.super }} {% endblock head_title %}
{% block content %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Store</title>
</head>

<h6>Books available</h6>
<ul>
    {% for obj in objects_list %}
    <li>{{obj}}<br>
        {{obj.book_image}} <br>
        {{obj.description}} <br>
        {{obj.author}}<br>
        {{obj.genre}}<br>
        {{obj.price}}<br>
        </li>


    {% endfor %}
</ul>


{% endblock content %}

Comment: You should put that as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView sends its data to the template as `object_list`, not `objects_list`.